# Return a JSON object from doview method of a basic portlet

Tags: portlet

I want to return a JSON object from the `doview` method of a basic portlet to `dojo.rawXhrPost` (handle as:xml) method of Javascript. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

*I am going to guess that you are working with [Java portlets](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification). There may be other solutions specific to your container, but you don't say what that is.*

The correct way to serve a resource from a portlet context is via the [serveResource](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/ResourceServingPortlet.html#serveResource(javax.portlet.ResourceRequest,%20javax.portlet.ResourceResponse)) method by using a [resource URL](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/ResourceURL.html). If you're still using JSR 168 portlets, you'll have to resort to using a servlet.

Any AJAX calls to a render URL to invoke [doView](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-api/apidocs/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html#doView(javax.portlet.RenderRequest,%20javax.portlet.RenderResponse)) are likely to re-render all your page's portlets and the surrounding theme. You'll have to deal with a load of junk data in your JavaScript and there may be unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

The  way to handle ajax calls is to use `resourceURL`.In `serveResource` send the result of ajax call as `response.getWriter().write(result)`. But if you want to use `renderURL` or `actionURL` you cannot handle the ajax calls as they'll load entire the portal page ( or can say as all the portlets in the portal page are loaded )